# Netlify Run build won't work. because of 'Unknown Word'

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, netlify

Pretty self explanatory. Netlify won't build react app. Previous versions build fine.
npm start works fine locally

[image: Screenshot of Netlify Deploy window]

I get similar results in Vscode running npm run build

[image: VScode npm run build error]

Comment: `Pretty self explanatory` - you could still add some more information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it had something to do with a key I put in `tailwind.config.js` as suggested by the tailwind docs:

[image]

I just had to remove the `important: true,` key and use the `!` modifier inline

e.g.
`className="!bg-green-500"`
Not sure why it wouldn't build with it. I updated postcss and tailwind just to make sure, but only removing it worked. Could someone who understands explain this.